# How to restrict the scroll to ListField itself instead of scrolling the whole screen in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I have implemented a customized ListField with some LabelFields. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

The problem is when I scroll the ListField, the whole scroll getting scrolled. Like this Screenshot..

[image]

I want the headerfield and the Field between header and the ListField to be stationary and only the listfield get scrolled. How can I achieve this?..Please help me...

Comment: Use setTitle(Field field). and add backbutton and event label to field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setBanner(Field field)` to create an area at the top of your screen which will always be visible.

By the way, you almost certainly don't need a 'Back' button in the top bar (like you would on an iPhone app) because all BlackBerrys have a physical back button for this purpose. The default action for it is to close the current screen (by popping it off the screen stack) and returning to the previous screen or closing the app if there are no more screens.

Comment: now the banner is not getting scrolled, but the field between the banner and the list(the black colored field in 1st image) also getting scrolled with list.I want only the list to be scrolled

Comment: You need to make sure that the black coloured field is added to the banner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 different managers and let only the manager that has the listfield to scroll